# Shipping methods are not showing at checkout. estimate shipping methods giving 404

Tags: magento

Whenever we go the checkout page on step 1 it shows no shipping methond

On debug found taht https://base-url/rest/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods is giving 404.

As you can see in this screenshot

[image]

Tried ways

1. Enabled the swagger and check whether this end point available or not. It was avaialbe.
2. Create one other custom api to check whether it is calling or not. Our custom api was also giving 404. As you can see in this screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After tried many different ways we found this one was the issue of the varnish cache. So if you are also facing this issue then please confirm whether cart pages are cached or not. The cart pages are never supposed to be cached.

So add a rule in default Varnish configuration where some of the routes concerning checkout by default are bypassed from being cached.

Hopefully bypassing the path "carts" and "rest" to make it work fine for your store.

Thank You!

Abbas